# compare two fields in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to compare and return error message if they are equal.

trying like this but not working

```
[['HRMS_candidateAlternateEmail'], '!compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'HRMS_candidateEmail'],
```

what will be write way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `!compare` to `compare`:

```
[['HRMS_candidateAlternateEmail'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'HRMS_candidateEmail', 'operator'=>'!='],
```

More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/698/model-validation-for-field-ranges-using-yii2-field-range-extension/) and [here](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/validation-rules-for-model-attributes-in-yiiframework-2-0/). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found it just added `'operator'=>'!='` and it works.

```
 [['HRMS_candidateAlternateEmail'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'HRMS_candidateEmail','operator'=>'!='],
```